# From ios with PHP to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I got a working code on getting the location.

I want to store the values from a textfield(i just leave it NULL for now), my longitude, latitude and timestamp.

This is the code where i send it to my php file

```
NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",   newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp];


NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/locatie.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString* postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", latitude, longitude,   stringFromDate];    
[request setValue:[NSString
                   stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And here's my code in my PHP File.

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database

$id = $POST['id'];
$longitude = $POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $POST['latitude'];
$timestamp = $POST['stringFromDate'];



$link = mysql_connect('server', 'name', 'pass')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('db_name') or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp)
        VALUES (NULL, $longitude,$latitude,$timestamp )");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

echo "OK";

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?
All the help is appreciated.

Thanks

**PS: I don't get any errors, the only thing is that my database stays empty**

**It's still not working, please if anybody knows what i'm doing wrong**

Comment: So what's your question? Please don't post some code and say "Its not working, tell me what to do!", please provide some error messages or whatever you get in your server log or ios log.

Comment: Well there are no errors. The only thing is. I don't get any values in my database, it stays empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the other answers about the `$_POST` global variable, I believe you have 2 PHP errors when you attempt to build your query string.

1. You aren't assigning the query string properly to the $query variable. You should use an equal sign to assign the string to the $query PHP variable. For example:

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO ..."
   ```
2. You need to concatenate the PHP variables ($longitude, $latitude, $timestamp) into the query string you are building using a period (`.`), which is the PHP concatenation operator. The concatenation allows PHP to dynamically build the string.

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp)
       VALUES (NULL," . $longitude . "," . $latitude . "," .$timestamp." )";
   ```

Depending on the format of the $timestamp string and datatypes in your table, you may need to wrap it in single quotes. `"'" . $timestamp . "'"`. Get some sample data for $longtitude, $latitude, $timestamp and try to write the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin or whatever DB tool you are using to see if you need quotes.

Also, the SQL Injection issue mentioned earlier should also be addressed. You are not sanitizing the strings you assigned to the $longitude, $latitude, $timestamp PHP variables from the $_POST global variable. You're passing them directly through to MySQL. This is where you can get into trouble if there are malicious statements in the strings.

Comment: Well written for the first answer, even IF the it wouldn't solve the problem. Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you Tom, hopefully David figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

It would be benificial if you included a description of what error you're observing.

However, it looks like you're using the wrong superglobal variable POST. It is actually found in `$_POST` (Note the underscore)

I would also suggest you reading up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as your code suffers from this dangerous vulnerability.

Comment: Well. There are no errors. The only thing is dat i don't see the values in my database. in my database they are all TEXT values. But there are no errors, only empty tabels

Comment: The behavior you were observing would've been excellent to include in your original description.

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

change `$POST` into `$_POST`. It's the current PHP notation.

Add form encoding to the data you send from your phone:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Change your requests postdata to this:

```
NSString* postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude=%@&longitude=%@&stringFromDate=%@", latitude, longitude,   stringFromDate];
```

You need to set the Post variables if you want to access them in your php script.

Comment: Thank you,

I changed it both. But my database is still empty

Comment: Try to dump your POST variable in your PHP script and see if any content arrives there. You should write the dump to a file on your disk or use e.g. the REST Extension for Firefox to test it, because when your send the request from your iPhone or simulator you won't see the PHP output.